# Import git repo with multiple initial commits into svn

Tags: git, import, git-svn

I basically have the following git repo layout

```
x ---- a -------------- b  -------------- c  ---->
         y -- 1 -- 2 -- ┛  z -- i -- j -- ┛
```

where `x`, `y`, `z` are initial commits. I have these multiple initial commits because I merged multiple git repositories into one big repositories using

```
git fetch git://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/<repo>
git merge --no-commit <repo>
git read-tree --reset -u HEAD
git read-tree -u --prefix=lib/<repo> <repo>
git commit -m "Pulling <repo>"
git branch -d <repo>
```

multiple times. All submodules basically had the same file layout.

To import the git repo into svn I initialized an empty svn repository and cloned it via

```
git svn clone http://some/svn/repo/my-project
```

then I tried

```
cd my-project
git remote add dev /path/to/working/git/big-repository
git pull dev master
git svn rebase
```

But the rebase fails because of some merge errors that appear to happen because all submodules had an identical file in their top-level (`pom.xml`)

Is there any any way I can import the git repository into svn keeping the history?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone else will provide a more graceful answer, but if the problem really is this one conflicting file you could probably use `git filter-branch` to remove the file from the project history.

[This page](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/) has an example.

Comment: I don't think that's it. Each submodule has the same layout (with `pom.xml` in its root directory) but they ended up in different directories in the big-repo. Somehow though when rebasing for svn they end up in the same directory. I assume this is because of the multiple initial commits.